# Problems with parsec types

Tags: haskell, parsec

In writing a parser for a particular computational biology file format, I'm running into some trouble.

Here's my code:

```
betaLine = string "BETA " *> p_int <*> p_int  <*> p_int <*> p_int <*> p_direction <*> p_exposure <* eol

p_int = liftA (read :: String -> Int) (many (char ' ') *> many1 digit <* many (char ' '))

p_direction = liftA mkDirection (many (char ' ') *> dir <* many (char ' '))
            where dir = oneStringOf [ "1", "-1" ]

p_exposure = liftA (map mkExposure) (many (char ' ') *> many1 (oneOf "io") <* many (char ' '))
```

Now, if I comment out the definition for betaLine, everything compiles and I've successfully tested out the individual parsers p_int, p_direction, and p_exposure.

But, when that betaLine equation is present, I get a type error that I don't quite understand. Is my understanding of the applicative <*> wrong? Ultimately, I want this to return Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Direction -> ExposureList, which I'll then be able to give to the constructor for a BetaPair.

The type error is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a5 -> a4 -> a3 -> a2 -> a1 -> a0'
            with actual type `Int'
Expected type: Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT
                 s0 u0 m0 (a5 -> a4 -> a3 -> a2 -> a1 -> a0)
  Actual type: Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s0 u0 m0 Int
In the second argument of `(*>)', namely `p_int'
In the first argument of `(<*>)', namely `string "BETA " *> p_int'
```

Comment: This is actually a problem with the associativity and precedence of the Applicative combinators - in a nutshell you need to use parens. If I remember correctly, UU_Parsing - which pioneered the Applicative style - had different associativity / precedence for `(*>)` and `(<*)` so it could get by with minimal parens.

Comment: That seems likely, as if I chop it down to only having one *> and one <*> it compiles. But, I can't quite figure out where the parens should go.

Comment: I think each use of `(<*)` or `(*>)` has to be parenthesized so the parser fragment in the third line would be something like this:  `((many (char ' ') *> dir) <* many (char ' '))`

Comment: The compiler is fine with that line as is; it's the betaLine definition that's problematic. But, putting parens around `string "BETA " *> p_int` and `p_exposure <* eol` does not fix it.

Comment: Mea culpa - discount what I've said then. Note that the betaLine isn't applying what it has parsed to a constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr**: you want this expression:

```
betaLine = string "BETA " *> (BetaPair <$> p_int <*> p_int  <*> p_int <*> p_int <*> p_direction <*> p_exposure) <* eol
```

Read *why* below.

---

Once again, this is partly a precedence issue. What your current line does:

```
string "BETA " *> p_int <*> p_int ...
```

... is that it creates a parser like this:

```
(string "BETA " *> p_int) <*> (p_int) ...
```

This is not the main issue, though, and as a matter of fact, the semantically wrong parser above would still yield the correct result, if the rest of the parser were correct. However, as you say, you have a slight misunderstanding about how `<*>` works. Its signature is:

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

As you can see, the function should get a function wrapped in a functor as the first argument, which it then **applies** using the value wrapped in the functor in the second argument (thus the **applicative** functor). When you give it `p_int` as the first argument at the beginning of your function, it is a `Parser Int` and not a `Parser (a -> b)`, so the types don't check.

And as a matter of fact, they cannot be made to type check if the goal is what you stated with your reasoning; you want `betaLine` to be a `Parser (Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Direction -> ExposureList)`, but how would that help you? You get a function that takes 4 `Int`s, a `Direction` and `ExposureList`, and when you give that function to the constructor of a `BetaPair`, it is magically supposed to construct a `BetaPair` out of it? Remember that functions associate to the right, so if the `BetaPair` constructor has type:

```
Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Direction -> ExposureList -> BetaPair
```

... it doesn't mean the same thing as:

```
(Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Direction -> ExposureList) -> BetaPair
```

It actually means this:

```
Int -> (Int -> (Int -> (Int -> (Direction -> (ExposureList -> BetaPair)))))
```

You can instead make the `betaLine` be a `Parser BetaPair`, which would make more sense. You can use the `<$>` operator, which is a synonym for `fmap` (under the function arrow), which lets you lift your `BetaPair` constructor into the `Parser` functor, and then apply individual arguments to it using the applicative functor interface. The `<$>` function has this type:

```
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

In this case, your first argument that you're lifting is the `BetaPair` constructor, which transforms the types `a` and `b` into the type components of the `BetaPair` "function", yielding this specific signature:

```
(<$>) :: (Int -> (Int -> (Int -> (Int -> (Direction -> (ExposureList -> BetaPair)))))) 
      -> f Int -> f (Int -> (Int -> (Direction -> (ExposureList -> BetaPair))))
```

As you can see, what the `<$>` will do here is to take a function as the left argument, and a value wrapped in a functor as the right argument, and apply the wrapped argument to the function.

As a simpler example, if you have `f :: Int -> String`, the following expression:

```
f <$> p_int
```

... will parse an integer, apply the function `f` with that integer as the argument, and wrap the result in the functor, so the expression above has type `Parser String`. The type of `<$>` in this position is:

```
(<$>) :: (Int -> String) -> Parser Int -> Parser String
```

So, using `<$>` applies the first argument to your constructor. So how do you deal with the other arguments? Well, this is where the `<*>` comes in, and I think that you understand from the type signature what it does: if you chain its use, it will successively apply one more argument to the function wrapped in the functor to the left, by unwrapping the functor to the right. So, for a simpler example again; say that you have a function `g :: Int -> Int -> String` and the following expression:

```
g <$> p_int <*> p_int
```

The `g <$> p_int` expression will apply the result of `p_int` to the first argument of `g`, so the type of that expression is `Parser (Int -> String)`. The `<*>` then applies the next argument, with the specific type of `<*>` being:

```
(<*>) :: Parser (Int -> String) -> Parser Int -> Parser String
```

So, the type of the whole expression above is `Parser String`.

Equivalently, for your situation, you can let `BetaPair` be your `g` in this case, yielding this pattern:

```
BetaPair <$> one <*> parser <*> per <*> argument <*> to <*> betaPair
```

As mentioned above, the resulting parser is thus:

```
betaLine = string "BETA " *> (BetaPair <$> p_int <*> p_int  <*> p_int <*> p_int <*> p_direction <*> p_exposure) <* eol
```

Comment: thanks, @dflemstr, I think this will solve my problem if I can figure out one last thing: one of those ints is actually not used by the BetaPair constructor (the fourth one). The constructor is actually `Int -> Int -> Int -> Direction -> ExposureList -> BetaPair`. What combination of parens and <* and *> will allow me to have that fourth Int _not_ be passed to the BetaPair constructor?

Comment: You can use `a *> b` which will ignore the result of `a` and just use the result of `b`. So, if the fourth `Parser Int` is unused, you can write `BetaPair <$> p_int <*> p_int <*> p_int <*> p_int *> p_direction ...`.

Comment: I tried that, and it doesn't compile. If I delete the last p_int completely it compiles (but of course won't parse the data):

    Couldn't match expected type `Direction' with actual type `Int'
    Expected type: Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s0 u0 m0 Direction
      Actual type: Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s0 u0 m0 Int
    In the second argument of `(<*>)', namely `p_int'
    In the first argument of `(*>)', namely
      `StrandPair <$> p_int <*> p_int <*> p_int <*> p_int'

Comment: Never mind, parens to the rescue; THAT was a precedence issue. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I made the same mistake as you made at first! You need parens around the `*>` arguments, like so: `BetaPair <$> p_int <*> p_int <*> p_int <*> (p_int *> p_direction) ...`. **EDIT**: Yeah, you got it.

Comment: In my experience sticking to using ‘<*‘ and ‘<$‘ with ‘<*>‘ and ‘<$>‘ lets you avoid conflicts. Just drop the ‘>‘ before any term you want to ignore. The only time ‘*>‘ works without parens are fairly trivial cases like open ‘*>‘ dostuff ‘<*‘ close, while the ‘<‘ variants chain arbitrarily.